# Getting the value of a razor textbox and appending values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to get pass the value of the textbox to the hidden field

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
@{
   var emailSubject = the value of @Html.TextboxFor( m => m.FirstName) + "Thank you for Contancting Us"
 }
@Html.Hidden(ThankyouNote, emailSubject)
```

if I use this code

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
@{
   var emailSubject = Model.Firstname + "Thank you for Contancting Us"
 }
@Html.Hidden(ThankyouNote, emailSubject)
```

I get an error that the Model.Firstname is null since the user has not entered any value on the textbox. So i want to get the value of the textbox to append it on the hidden field without going back to the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Model.Firstname` is still null when the textbox value changed because the code runs server-side, and changes in client-side doesn't reflect immediately to server-side code.

If you want to append text into hidden field when textbox value changed at the same time, use client-side `keyup` (or `onkeyup`) event instead:

**JS (jQuery)**

```
$('#FirstName').keyup(function () {
    var text = $(this).val();

    var emailSubject = text + "Thank you for Contacting Us";

    $('#ThankyouNote').val(emailSubject);
});
```

**Note:** You can use `change`/`onchange` event, but the event will trigger when the textbox losing focus instead of when user starts typing characters.

Working example: [.NET Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JEhyqg)